# Get file data from REST

Tags: rest, file, api

I am trying to find a way to combine two rest calls so that it gives me the correct files as well as the relevant data.

This call gives me the correct data

```
/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules
```

This call gives me the correct files

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/Landing%20Pages')/Files
```

Is there a way to combine these two so that I get the correct files as well as the correct data for those files?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine these two by `$expanding` `ListItemAllFields` column of the `File`. `ListItemAllFields` is `__deferred` property of `File`. I believe you know that we need to `$expand` all `Lookup` columns and `__deferred` properties to get information. Anyway, from `ListItemAllFields` you can get all information what you get from `/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules`.

## Combined End-Point is

```
var baseUrl = "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/Landing Pages')/Files?";

var selectQuery = "$select=ListItemAllFields/ID,ListItemAllFields/Title,ListItemAllFields/FileRef,ListItemAllFields/Modules&";

var expandQuery = "$expand=ListItemAllFields";

var combinedUrl = baseUrl + selectQuery + expandQuery;
```

For testing and exploring REST API, you can use my [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd).

[image]

Find more about `$expand` in my article [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)